# Agregar HTML dentro de variable PHP de texto

Tags: php, html, css

Tengo en la página de mi cliente un formulario de contacto tal así:

```
<form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate="novalidate">
  <div>
    <div>
      <label>Name</label>
      <input id="name" type="text" required="required">
      <p></p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div>
      <label>mail</label>
      <input id="email" type="email" required="required">
      <p></p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div>
      <label>phone</label>
      <input id="phone" type="tel" required="required">
      <p></p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div>
      <label>Message</label>
      <textarea id="message" required="required"></textarea>
      <p></p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="success"></div>
  <div>
    <button type="submit" id="sendMessageButton">Send</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Cuando envío el formulario, le llega al correo de mi cliente un texto plano con el mensaje, algo como esto:

[image: como se ve en el correo]

Este es PHP que hace el envío:

```
<?php
// Check for empty fields
if(empty($_POST['name'])        ||
   empty($_POST['email'])       ||
   empty($_POST['phone'])       ||
   empty($_POST['message']) ||
   !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
   {
    echo "empty";
    return false;
   }

$name = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
$email_address = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']));
$phone = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['phone']));
$message = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']));

// Create the email and send the message
$to = 'micliente@mail.com'; // Add your email address inbetween the '' replacing yourname@yourdomain.com - This is where the form will send a message to.
$email_subject = "misitio.com - $name te escribió";
$email_body = "Tiene un nuevo mensaje en su pagina de misitio.com\n\n"."Estos son los detalles:\n\nNombre: $name\n\nEmail: $email_address\n\nTelefono: $phone\n\nMensaje:\n$message";
$headers = "From: noreply@misitio.com\n"; // This is the email address the generated message will be from. We recommend using something like noreply@yourdomain.com.
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
return true;
?>
```

Quisiera saber si es posible aplicar etiquetas html con su respectivo CSS dentro de estas cadenas de texto, por ejemplo:

```
$email_body = "<h3>Tiene un nuevo mensaje en su pagina de <b>misitio.com</b><h3> <p>Estos son los detalles:</p><div class="detalle"><p>Nombre: $name ... etc </div>";
```

Cuando lo intento claramente me lo toma como texto plano a excepción de los valores `$n`

Nota: Uso jsBootstrapValidation

Les agradezco su cordial ayuda

Comment: Podes agregar etiquetas css en el head de tu html sin problemas

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario @oegpyg, no debería ser en el PHP? En mi html solamente relleno el formulario (que ya tiene CSS, solo lo he quitado del código por simplicidad). Lo que quiero es que al llegar al correo me muestre algo de estilo

Comment: PD: Sé que los estilos en un gestor mail pueden ser limitados, pero sólo quisiera saber si es esto posible

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Puedes hacer el contenido que va a tener el `email` en un `html` a parte y lo incluyes en el mensaje así

```
$message = utf8_decode(file_get_contents("../templateEmail.html"));
```

y en ese `html` puedes hacerle todo el `css`, es recomendable que lo hagas en el mismo archivo para que no haya errores de que no cargue los estilos, o sí lo quieres hacer en el mismo `php` puedes hacerlo, con la misma estructura de un `html` solo que, toma en cuenta de que te queda muy extenso

Demo:

`HTML templateEmail.html`

```
<<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<style text/css> </style> //Metes todo el css que necesites solamente en el head
</head>
<body> 
    <label> Tienes un nuevo mensaje de misitio.com </label>
    <br>
    <h5> Detalles: </h5>
    <br>
    <label>Nombre: {{nombre}} </label>
</body>
</html>
```

`PHP` tal cual como lo tienes, solo te muevo la variable `$email_body` y agrego algo más

```
$email_body = utf8_decode(file_get_contents("../templateEmail.html"));
$email_body = str_replace('{{nombre}}', $name, $message)
```

Y de la misma manera con lo otro, sí tienes alguna otra duda o no te sirve, me dices

Comment: Cómo podría adaptar esto a mi código sin que afecte mis variables? Podrías mostrarme un ejemplo así sea sencillo para guiarme un poco mejor? Te agradezco amigo

Comment: Ya te muestro algo simple y te haces una idea

Comment: Listo, mira a ver sí te sirve

Comment: Muchas gracias, voy a revisarlo

Answer (score 2):

te recomiendo que uses PHPMailer, te permite enviar correos con formato HTML.

Acá lo puedes bajar: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Aparte te dejo un ejemplo de como armar un mail con PHPMailer.

```
    <?php

    require_once('../Modelo/PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php'); //LLAMAS A LA LIBRERIA PHP MAILER QUE BAJARAS DESDE LA GITHUB

    $mail=new PHPMailer(); // CREAS UN NUEVO OBJETO


    $mail->isSMTP();  //DECLARAS QUE EL TIPO DE ENVIO ES SMTP

    //$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;     // Enable verbose debug output 

    $mail->Debugoutput='html';      // ESTABLECES EL FORMATO HTML             

    $mail->Host = 'ejemplo@ejemplo.com';  // ESPECIFICAS EL SERVIDOR SMTP DEL CORREO QUE COLOCARAS COMO FROM

    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;    // Enable SMTP authentication

    $mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true; // SMTP connection will not close after each email sent

    $mail->Port =587;     // TCP port to connect to

    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'TLS';      // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted   

    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';

    $mail->IsHTML(true);     

    $mail->Username = 'ejemplo@ejemplo.com';    // EL CORREO QUE DESDE EL QUE SE ENVIARAN LOS MAILS

    $mail->Password = 'XXXXXXXX';     // CONTRASEÑA DEL CORREO
    $mail->setFrom('Direccion from', 'Nombre que quieres que muestre'); 

    //$mail->AddReplyTo($email, $nombre);   


    //$mail->addAddress($email); // DESTINATARIO

    $mail->Subject = 'AQUI VA EL ASUNTO';   

    $mail->Body    = "<!DOCTYPE html> // AQUI ARMAS EL HTML CON EL ESTILO CSS QUE QUIERAS VER EN EL CORREO
    <html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='UTF-8'>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>



    </body>
    </html>";      



    if(!$mail->send()) {
        echo "<script>alert('Error en el envío, inténtelo de nuevo')</script>";



    } 
    else {
        echo "<script>alert('Se ha enviado el correo')</script>";

        ?>
```

Comment: Gracias por la sugerencia José, pero ya tengo algo implementado y no quisiera cambiarlo, aparte tener que poner la contraseña de mi correo no es muy entusiasmante.